# Tree traversal sequence in Binary Search Tree

Tags: permutations, trees

I came across this question. However, I don't know how to approach this and solve. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

> When searching for the key value 30 in a binary search tree, nodes
>   containing the key values **10, 20, 40, 50, 70 80, 90** are traversed, **not
>   necessarily in the order given**. How many different orders are possible
>   in which these key values can occur on the search path from the root
>   to the node containing the value 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the keys are encountered, then the keys $10$ and $20$ have to be in that order, and the keys $90$, $80$, $70$, $50$, $40$ have to be in that order; these two groups can be interleaved in an arbitary way, which allows for $\binom{5+2}2=21$ different orders.

If only some, not necessarily all the keys are encountered, we can choose $0\le k\le2$ of the values $10$, $20$ and $0\le l\le5$ of the values $40$, $50$, $70$, $80$, $90$. Each of the two groups has to be ordered in itself, but the two groups can be interleaved in an arbitrary way. That makes

$$
\sum_{k=0}^2\sum_{l=0}^5\binom2k\binom5l\binom{k+l}k=528\;.
$$

[Here's the Wolfram|Alpha computation.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=sum%20of%20(sum%20of%20binom%20(2,k)%20*%20binom%20(5,l)%20*%20binom%20(k%2Bl,k)%20for%20k%3D0..2)%20for%20l%3D0..5)

Comment: Thanks, this cleared things up! :)

Answer (score 1):

We can divide this into two set of values, smaller than $30$ and greater than $30$. 
$$(\color{blue}{10,20},\color{red}{40,50,70,80,90})$$

The values in blue are smaller than $30$ $\mbox{ }\color{blue}{10,20}$

The values in red are greater than $30$  $\mbox{ }\color{red}{40,50,70,80,90}$

Path to the node  $30$ has involved those nodes. So, the possible solution to the given problem is 
$$\{S,S,S,S,S,L,L\}$$
So, the total number of possible ways $=$ all permutations of that set which is $=\dfrac{7!}{2!\times5!}$

Therefore, different orders are possible in which these key values can occur on the search path from the root to the node containing the value $30$ is $21$

Comment: Your answer matches the expected answer. Can you please edit your answer to explain how and why you applied the formula in the 3rd step.

Comment: @DebanikDawn See the edit where I explained it.